# While and for combination in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, for-loop, while-loop

So, there is a problem that I've just solved, but i would like to know why did one of my methods didn't work properly.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
class scanClass extends Thread {

    public compareClass cc;
    private String name;
    final int MaxCards = 10;
    double d;
    double[] Player1Array = new double[MaxCards];
    double[] Player2Array = new double[MaxCards];
    String Player1Cards = " 23 fj 24 dkk 9 djjj 12 34 5 4 323 5 12 998 34 2 djj 30 djj 39 dsds 23 ";
    String Player2Cards = " mdk 93 fjf 38 89 1 fjdj 49 20 fjfj 48 jd 299 jd 3 dk 39 dk 394 1 3";

    scanClass(compareClass compareclass,String s){
        cc = compareclass;
        name = s;
    }

    public void scan1(){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(Player1Cards);

        for(int i=0;i<Player1Array.length && scan.hasNext();i++){

            if(!scan.hasNextDouble()) scan.next();
            d = scan.nextDouble();
            Player1Array[i]=d;      

        }
        scan.close();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Player1Array));
    }

    public void scan2(){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(Player2Cards);

        for(int i=0;i<Player2Array.length;i++){
            while(scan.hasNext()) {
                if(!scan.hasNextDouble())
                    scan.next();
                double d = scan.nextDouble();
                Player2Array[i]=d;
            }
        }
        scan.close();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Player2Array));
    }

    public void run(){
        if(name.equals("Player1")) scan1();
        if(name.equals("Player2")) scan2();
    }
}
```

Well, the method scan1() does work properly, but scan2() scans only one double, and it's for some reason the last in the scanned String.

Thank you for your help, my dear friends!

Comment: Is this compilable? The braces don't seem to match up (e.g. the opening brace in `scan2` for your `while` loop doesn't have a matching closing brace).

Answer (score 2):

You have to break the while loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Player2Array.length; i++) {
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        if (!scan.hasNextDouble()) {
            scan.next();
        }
        double d = scan.nextDouble();
        Player2Array[i] = d;
        break; // break the loop
    }
}
```

Otherwise you never reach the outer loop again and the array can not be populated.

Comment: If he breaks the loop in the first iteration, then what is the point in using a `while` loop? Maybe you should suggest to use an `if` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You inner loop assigned all the doubles to the first value of `i` and there was no input after than. i.e. it starts `while(scan.hasNext()){` which consumes all the input.

This is where stepping through your code in your debugger would be helpful ;)

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me, but the second method makes absolut no sense to me. If you use a while loop, you don't have to use also a for loop around this for counting up a counter variable. You can initialize a counter variable, which will getting higher in every while loop iteration.

```
int countVariable = 0;
while(scan.hasNext())
{
countVariable++;
        if(!scan.hasNextDouble()) scan.next();
        double d = scan.nextDouble();
        Player2Array[countVariable]=d;
}
```

Comment: Well, is there a reason for keeping the initial `0` on index `0` of the `Player2Array` array?

Comment: Right, it should be used at the end not in the beginning! :)